# A number of Trimmomatic trimming parameters not working in Snakemake wrapper

Tags: snakemake

Previously my `Trimmomatic` shell command included the following trimmers:

> ILLUMINACLIP:adapters.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36

For the [Snakemake wrapper for Trimmomatic](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrappers/trimmomatic/pe.html?highlight=trimmomatic) only `LEADING:3` and `MINLEN:36` work in the `params: trimmer`:

```
rule trimming:
    input:
        r1 = lambda wildcards: getHome(wildcards.sample)[0],
        r2 = lambda wildcards: getHome(wildcards.sample)[1]
    output:
        r1 = os.path.join(dirs_dict["TRIM_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}_R1_trim_paired.fastq.gz"),
        r1_unpaired = os.path.join(dirs_dict["TRIM_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}_R1_trim_unpaired.fastq.gz"),
        r2 = os.path.join(dirs_dict["TRIM_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}_R2_trim_paired.fastq.gz"),
        r2_unpaired = os.path.join(dirs_dict["TRIM_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}_R2_trim_unpaired.fastq.gz")
    log: os.path.join(dirs_dict["LOG_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}.log")
    threads: 32
    params:
    # list of trimmers (see manual)
        trimmer=["LEADING:3", "MINLEN:36"],
        # optional parameters
        extra="",
        compression_level="-9"
    resources:
    mem = 1000,
        time = 120
    message: """--- Trimming FASTQ files with Trimmomatic."""
    wrapper:
    "0.64.0/bio/trimmomatic/pe"
```

When trying to use any of the other parameters (`ILLUMINACLIP:adapters.fa:2:30:10 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15`) it fails.

For example, trying only `TRAILING:3`:

```
rule trimming:
    input:
        r1 = lambda wildcards: getHome(wildcards.sample)[0],
        r2 = lambda wildcards: getHome(wildcards.sample)[1]
    output:
        r1 = os.path.join(dirs_dict["TRIM_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}_R1_trim_paired.fastq.gz"),
        r1_unpaired = os.path.join(dirs_dict["TRIM_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}_R1_trim_unpaired.fastq.gz"),
        r2 = os.path.join(dirs_dict["TRIM_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}_R2_trim_paired.fastq.gz"),
        r2_unpaired = os.path.join(dirs_dict["TRIM_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}_R2_trim_unpaired.fastq.gz")
    log: os.path.join(dirs_dict["LOG_DIR"],config["TRIM_TOOL"],"{sample}.log")
    threads: 32
    params:
    # list of trimmers (see manual)
        trimmer=["TRAILING:3"],
        # optional parameters
        extra="",
        compression_level="-9"
    resources:
    mem = 1000,
        time = 120
    message: """--- Trimming FASTQ files with Trimmomatic."""
    wrapper:
    "0.64.0/bio/trimmomatic/pe"
```

Results in the following error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
        1   qc_before_align_r1
        1

[Mon Sep 14 13:42:08 2020]
Job 0: --- Quality check of raw data with FastQC before alignment.

Activating conda environment: /home/moldach/wrappers/.snakemake/conda/975fb1fd
Activating conda environment: /home/moldach/wrappers/.snakemake/conda/975fb1fd
Skipping ' 2> logs/fastqc/before_align/MTG324_R1.log' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Failed to process file MTG324_R1_trim_paired.fastq.gz
uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.SequenceFormatException: Ran out of data in the middle of a fastq entry.  Your file is probably truncated
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.FastQFile.readNext(FastQFile.java:179)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Sequence.FastQFile.next(FastQFile.java:125)
        at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.AnalysisRunner.run(AnalysisRunner.java:77)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
mv: cannot stat ‘/tmp/tmpsnncjthh/MTG324_R1_trim_paired_fastqc.html’: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moldach/wrappers/.snakemake/scripts/tmpp34b98yj.wrapper.py", line 47, in <module>
    shell("mv {html_path:q} {snakemake.output.html:q}")
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 205, in __new__
    raise sp.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'set -euo pipefail;  mv /tmp/tmpsnncjthh/MTG324_R1_trim_paired_fastqc.html qc/fastQC/before_align/MTG324_R1_trim_paired_fastqc.html' returned non-zero exit status $
[Mon Sep 14 13:45:16 2020]
Error in rule qc_before_align_r1:
    jobid: 0
    output: qc/fastQC/before_align/MTG324_R1_trim_paired_fastqc.html, qc/fastQC/before_align/MTG324_R1_trim_paired_fastqc.zip
    log: logs/fastqc/before_align/MTG324_R1.log (check log file(s) for error message)
    conda-env: /home/moldach/wrappers/.snakemake/conda/975fb1fd

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 181 of /home/moldach/wrappers/Trim:
Command 'source /home/moldach/anaconda3/bin/activate '/home/moldach/wrappers/.snakemake/conda/975fb1fd'; set -euo pipefail;  python /home/moldach/wrappers/.snakemake/scripts/tmpp34b98yj.wrapper.py' retu$
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2189, in run_wrapper
  File "/home/moldach/wrappers/Trim", line 181, in __rule_qc_before_align_r1
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 529, in _callback
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 515, in cached_or_run
  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 2201, in run_wrapper
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Comment: Code shown is for rule `trimming` whereas the error is from rule `qc_before_align_r1`. Perhaps you are looking at the wrong rule to debug? Providing a minimal example could make it easy to identify the issue.

Comment: I guess his problem is that Trimmomatic returns fastq-files which will raise an error in the qc-step. But an example of such a file would be great, the wrapper normally does not much more than reporting the params to the tool, so I wonder what causes the problem here.

Comment: There is no error thrown from `trimming` Manavalan. Trimmomatic works, as jafors says, and returns fastq-files; however, the error is raised at the fastQC step. Let me try this on some published data then I'll share a dropbox link to data soon